# Fast replacement of tzinfo of a pandas.Series of datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a `pandas.Series`of datetime and need to replace the tzinfo for every element in it.

I know how to do it using `apply` with python function but it's very slow: ~16s for 1M elements on a MacBookPro

```
In [71]: s = pd.date_range('2015-1-1', freq='h', periods=1e6).to_series().reset_index(drop=True)

In [72]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc))
1 loops, best of 3: 16.7 s per loop
```

Is there a numpy ufunc function for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`dt.localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html#pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize):

```
In [33]:
import pytz
%timeit s.dt.tz_localize(pytz.utc)
%timeit s.apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc))

10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 10.4 s per loop
```

As you can see ~100X faster